# Static Storage Class C++ Count

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and was wondering why the below while loop stops at 0 when compiled and executed?

```
#include <iostream>

void func(void);

static int count = 10;

int main() {

while(count--) {
  func();
   }

   return 0;
}


void func( void ) {
static int i = 5; // local static variable
i++;
std::cout << "i is " << i ;
std::cout << " and count is " << count << std::endl;
}
```

The example is from: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_storage_classes.htm

Comment: What do you mean with "stops at 0"? What is the output you get from the program? What is the output you expected? Perhaps you should take some time to learn how to use a *debugger* and how to step through your program line by line, while at the same time watch variables and their values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 10 loops, it will be evaluating count when count is zero.  Conditionals in c++ only advance if the condition is nonzero, so once count hits zero, it'll stop.

On the final couple loops, execution will look like:

- evaluates condition when count is 1: count is nonzero, so it continues to do the loop body
- postfix decrements count, so count becomes zero *after* the condition is evaluated
- func() prints out i and count, which is now zero.
- evaluates condition now that count is 0: condition is zero, so it stops and doesn't print anything else.

Comment: Thank you!  The "conditionals in C++ only advance if the condition is nonzero" helped out.  I come from Javascript where while loops would keep going.

Comment: In Java the language enforces that the input to conditionals is a boolean, so you can't just put an int in there.